# Xamarin Forms WebView Load embedded in application site

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, blazor

I have embedded site in my assembly:

```cs
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WebView.Navigating += WebView_Navigating;
            var resourceName = Program.GetResourceName("index.html");
            WebView.Source = new UrlWebViewSource()
            {
                Url = "file://" + resourceName,
            };
        }

        public void WebView_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Url.StartsWith("file://"))
            {
                return;
            }

            Device.OpenUri(new Uri(args.Url));

            args.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

I have tried to figure out how to run it using `WebView` using `Xamarin.Forms` ...
I have got embedded resource from my assembly and I need somehow to load text based html into WebView ...

But I did not know how to do this ...
Is there some API for loading Embedded Resource into WebView ?

After some research I have found some solution:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BlazorXamarinMobile.Web.Client;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace BlazorXamarinMobile
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> _urlToHtml = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WebView.Navigating += WebView_Navigating;
            (string embeddedResource, string text) = Program.GetResourceName("index.html");
            embeddedResource = embeddedResource.Replace("wwwroot.index.html", "wwwroot/index.html");
            var embeddedResourceUrl = "file://" + embeddedResource;
            _urlToHtml.Add("file://BlazorXamarinMobile.Web.Client.wwwroot/".ToLower(), text);
            _urlToHtml.Add(embeddedResourceUrl.ToLower(), text);
            WebView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource()
            {
                BaseUrl = "file://BlazorXamarinMobile.Web.Client.wwwroot/".ToLower(),
                Html = text,
            };
        }

        public void WebView_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Url.StartsWith("file://"))
            {
                if (args.Url.Contains("wwwroot/"))
                {
                    var html = _urlToHtml[args.Url];
                    WebView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource()
                    {
                        Html = html,
                    };
                }
                return;
            }

            args.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

But WebView shows that Url is invalid !!
But if I load text directly it shows initial site and error to Reload application ... It happens due to that WebView tries to load from custom path files, but those files are inside of Assembly and it should be loaded manually with some kind of hook ...

Is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load the enbeded site with webview, you could try the steps below.

Html: index.hyml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Xamarin Forms</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1>
<p>This is an Android web page.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Xaml:

```
  <ContentPage.Content>             
        <WebView x:Name="Webview_html" />       
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Code Behind：XamarinDemo is my Xamarin.Forms project. I put the html embeded resource under the Form project.

```
string fileName = "XamarinDemo.index.html";

        var assembly = typeof(XamarinDemo.MainPage).Assembly;

        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fileName);
        if (stream == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                String.Format("Cannot create stream from specified URL: {0}", fileName));
        }

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string htmlString = reader.ReadToEnd();

        HtmlWebViewSource html = new HtmlWebViewSource();
        html.Html = htmlString;

        Webview_html.Source = html;
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Zand Thank you for support, but I did the same and it works with the page that do not have links to other resources located in my Assembly ... What I want is somehow to add Url hooks on WebView loading resources and if this Url is a file to load it from my Assembly

Comment: What does the Url hooks mean? I confused about that and need more information.

Comment: When I load html as you did then WebView will try to load all resources: css, javascript, *.dll (for Blazor) and so on, but all this data located in C# Assembly and cannot easily be loaded to WebView and the nice thing would be to have catch when WebView will try to load this file to load it manually from Assembly

Comment: yeah, the embeded resource in Xamarin.forms would be loaded like that. And i seen another comment, you put the embeded resource in dll file. What is the dll file? What is the relationship between this dll file and Xamarin.forms project? Why do you put the html in this dll file?

Comment: I have project where is embedded resources, this project is not Android or iOS and resources located inside of dll-file and I need somehow to load this resource using WebView

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are not referencing the location correctly, and possibly even placed your html file in an incorrect location. What tutorial are you following, did you follow the official documentation for [Xamarin Forms Web Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#local-html-content)?

- You have to place the files in the right location- Assets in Android and Resources on iOS.
- And then you have to get the BaseURL in the right way for each platform using DependencyService
- And then, on Android you have to use a stream reader to read the file

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have my site inside of my Assembly as embedded resources, but WebView tries to open Url to files that is located inside of my assembly and I need some Url hook for loading this files not from Url but from my assembly

Comment: What do you mean from assembly? Could you share a picture of where it is located? Is there a reason why you can’t place it as shown here?

Comment: I mean that I have embedded resources in my C# Assembly (dll file)

Comment: Yes and which folder do you store it in?

Comment: In wwwroot as in Blazor WebAssembly application and this folder located inside of dll, but WebView on Android cannot read from C# dll directly, it can read only from .aar file and folder inside this file, but I do not have such folder, but I have this folder in my dll

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your solution explorer

Comment: Also what tutorial are you trying to follow